# Gradle create args in custom run tasks

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build

I am new to Gradle and I am definitely missing something but this basic question is quite a mystery to me.

I am trying to create multiple custom tasks wrapping a Gradle 'run' from the application plugin, which inside to create one or more args depending on the custom task's need.
I do not want to pass arguments from the CLI*, I want those to be created inside the run-wrapping Gradle task.

Let's see an example use of what I am trying to achieve:

```
// Main.kt
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   for (a in args)
      println("$a ") // prints 'env1' or 'env2 5' (see gradle.build)
}

// gradle.build, unworking attempt 1
gradle.registerTask("customA") {
   description = "run wrapper 1"

   doFirst {
     gradle.run.configure {
        systemProperty("-Dtask", "env1")
     }
   }
   finalizedBy("run") 
}

// gradle.build, unworking attempt 2
gradle.registerTask("customB") {
   description = "run wrapper 2"
   args = listOf("env2", "5")

   finalizedBy("run") 
}

// Then use as
./gradlew customA

// Essentially I want the above command to be equal to ./gradlew run --args=['env2', '5']
```

The program isn't Spring Boot, it's a small kotlin project. Hence, I want it to run as a programme, not as a jar. Unfortunately, whenever I use the 'args' property, Gradle starts looking for a jar, can't think of a way around it.
The first option (the customA task), doesn't feed the argument in the main's args list but I guess it will be accessible via getProperty() which doesn't satisfy my requirements.

Could you please show me the right way to do what I am trying to?

* there are many topics on how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first attempt is setting a system property, not an application argument. Your second attempt is setting the arguments of the `customB` task, not the `run` task. There may be a better approach for what you want, but the following seems to work:

**Main.kt**

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) = println(args.contentToString())
```

**build.gradle.kts** ([Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)):

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.20"
    application
}

application {
    mainClass.set("MainKt")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}

tasks {
    val run by existing(JavaExec::class)

    register("customA") {
        doFirst {
            run.configure {
                args = listOf("Hello", "World!")
            }
        }
        finalizedBy(run)
    }

    register("customB") {
        doFirst {
            run.configure {
                args = listOf("Goodbye", "World!")
            }
        }
        finalizedBy(run)
    }
}
```

With the above I get the following outputs:

| Executing | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `./gradlew customA` | `[Hello, World!]` |
| `./gradlew customB` | `[Goodbye, World!]` |

Comment: Comprehensive and well-written answer. Thank you for your time. Thank you very much!